# MODBUS example QT framework' file .pro

Tags: c++, qt5, qt-creator, qmake

```
> QT += serialbus serialport widgets
> requires(qtConfig(combobox))                  // @1
> qtConfig(modbus-serialport): QT += serialport // @2
```

Is there someone who can explain to me these 2 lines or give me a relating document to this? I found it in QT Framework's example for Modbus's communication.

Comment: What that I could find on the topic: **qtconfig** was Qt 4 tool to configure fonts, icons or styles: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/qt#Qt4_style_not_respected . As for **requires(condition)** - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#requires-condition . Bookmark also - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html and https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake